# Can a node module require a vanilla js file?

Tags: node.js, webpack

Trying to fast-forward through my node+npm+webpack learning, and here's a simple boolean question: can a node module js file require a vanilla js file? Or, do I need to "node-ify" the vanilla js with a module.exports?

Comment: Define "vanilla".  Are you trying to get the vanilla file to export data to another file?  It would be really helpful if you could add some code to demonstrate what you are trying to do and what you are asking.

Comment: Say: var function1 = function() {} Could I call function1 from the dependent node module?

Comment: I'm assuming "no" given what a module is supposed to be (and the use of var keyword for scope).

Answer (score 0):

In some tests, I've seen that a module.exports isn't required to "node-ify" some vanilla js. What is required is a parent folder for the vanilla js that also contains a package.json that specifies a main js entry file. Then, it's npm-installable into other node modules. module.exports is for a module's api.